# Unity C#, objects spawning in wrong position

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, spawn

I'm trying to spawn objects one by one with +0.6 space on Y axis. Objects should be 0.6, 1.2, 1.8, 2.4, 3 etc while it looks like this 0.6, 1.8, 3.6, 6, 9 etc..
I dont know whats going on so i hope you can help me, here's a code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject cubeOne, cubeDouble, cubeTriple, cubeQuattro, cubeOneShort, cubeDoubleShort, cubeTripleShort, cubeQuattroShort, sphereOne, sphereDouble, sphereTriple, sphereQuattro, sphereOneShort, sphereDoubleShort, sphereTripleShort, sphereQuattroShort;
int whatToSpawn;
float position;
int yRotation;

void Update () {

        whatToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 5);
        position += 0.6f;
        Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
        newPosition.y += position;

        switch (whatToSpawn)
        {
            case 1:
                Instantiate(cubeOne, transform.position = newPosition, transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
                Debug.Log(position);
                break;
            case 2:
                Instantiate(cubeDouble, transform.position = newPosition, transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
                Debug.Log(position);
                break;
            case 3:
                Instantiate(cubeTriple, transform.position = newPosition, transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
                Debug.Log(position);
                break;
            case 4:
                Instantiate(cubeQuattro, transform.position = newPosition, transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
                Debug.Log(position);
                break;
        }
   }
}
```

thank you for answers.

Comment: The transform.position of the spawner is never changed so that is perfectly valid.

Comment: @TheFish I gave it a second glance: Yes, it does: "Instantiate(cubeOne, **transform.position = newPosition**,", doesn't it?

Comment: I believe that to be the mistake in the logic. I don't think that was deliberate.

Comment: @TheFish Yep, +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are trying to use the Instantiate overload `public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);`.

The code in the Instantiate is moving the transform.position of the spawner. Change your instantiate code to:

```
Instantiate(cubeOne, newPosition, transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

You add `position` to `newposition` and increase `position` by 0.6 each time and assign it to the spawning object. So what I see is like that:

```
 loops  |  position | newposition |  p + np  =  result
-------------------------------------------------------
      1 |     0.6   |      0      |  0+0.6   =  0.6
             +0.6           .-------------------↵
               ↓           ↓
      2 |     1.2   |     0.6     |  1.2+0.6 =  1.8
             +0.6           .-------------------↵
               ↓           ↓
      3 |     1.8   |     1.8     |  1.8+1.8 =  3.6
```

And so on...

So I think it is just mathematical. What Fish proposed solves it therefore.